# Java variable doesn't get updated by different instances/threads

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, nodes

So I have a pretty complex (for me) project for my uni. I have to essentially create a Spotify-like program using the Event Delivery System with sockets and threads. To put my problem simply, I want to run 3 broker instances at the same time. Broker.java class extends the Node.java class in which there is an ArrayList:

```
public static ArrayList<Broker> BrokerList= new ArrayList<Broker>();
```

in which I want to add each broker node as I open it. Until I solve my problem my Broker Main class looks like this and I want to run 3 instances of this main where I manually change the port each time before I run it:

```
public class BrokMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
         Broker brok = new Broker(4446, "localhost");
         brok.startServer();
    }
}
```

and the startServer method inside Broker class looks like this:

```
public void startServer() {
    ServerSocket listenerSocket = null;
    BrokerList.add(this);
    this.brokHash = hashString(ipAddress + Integer.toString(this.port));
    try {
        listenerSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        while (true) { 
            System.out.println("Server is up and waiting ");
            listenerSocket.accept();
            Thread t = new Thread(this);
            t.start();
            t.join();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

So clearly in this method I add this broker to the BrokerList, but even if I run 3 different instances of the brokMain, whenever I try to print the size of the list, I get 1. I feel like this is a thread sychronization issue? Any suggestions?

Comment: Where and how do you define BrokerList? If every Broker has it's own broker list then this is expected behavior. You need to use a shared list and pass it to Broker as an constructor argument as one of the options.

Comment: @Ivan I define the BrokerList as shown above in Node which is the parent class to Broker. How do I set up a shared list and where?

Comment: Tried @Volatile annotation?

Comment: If this is a thread synchronization issue, changing the BrokerList to a [CopyOnWriteArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) together with making the BrokerList `final` should solve the issue. If not, something else is wrong.